# Canvas with Zoom Animation

Tags: c#, wpf

i am developing a small app in WPF and trying to set up an animation of zoom (using ZoomSlider) for a canvas but without good result ,do you have any suggestion how do a nice animation meantime is zooming the Canvas?

Thanks so much for your attention .

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Jossef Goldberg posted a VirtualizedCanvas for WPF way back in 2008 on his blog. The code not only contains a virtualized canvas (which you probably don't neeed - it is usually overkill) but also has some gestures such as (animated) zooming and panning.

You can download the code from his blog:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jgoldb/virtualized-wpf-canvas

This should give you a great starting point how to do it for your own canvas.